# Asyncio HTTP Request Queue

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, asynchronous

I wrote a simple sitemap.xml checker using asyncio and aiohttp. I followed the [documentation](http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/producer_consumer.html) demonstrating the producer/consumer pattern. However, I noticed that as the URLs scale larger, it seems to get slower in performance. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Can I improve request speed?

**Use case**:

When `check()` is given the URL https://www.google.com/flights/sitemap.xml with ~310 links, it takes approximately 00:03:24 minutes to complete. Github [source](https://github.com/1-hit/sitemapcheck) code is available if needed.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from timeit import default_timer as timer
from sys import exit as abort

import time
import sys
import logging
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import defusedxml.ElementTree

class Logger(object):

    FMT = '%(name)s: %(levelname)s: %(message)s'

    def __init__(self):
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self._logger.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)

        stdout = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
        stderr = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stderr)

        stdout.setLevel(level=logging.INFO)
        stderr.setLevel(level=logging.WARNING)

        stdout.addFilter(lambda record: record.levelno == logging.INFO)

        stdout.setFormatter(
            logging.Formatter(
                fmt=self.FMT,
                datefmt=None,
                style='%'))
        stderr.setFormatter(
            logging.Formatter(
                fmt=self.FMT,
                datefmt=None,
                style='%'))

        self._logger.addHandler(hdlr=stdout)
        self._logger.addHandler(hdlr=stderr)

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._logger.hasHandlers():
            return
        for handler in self._logger.handlers:
            if isinstance(handler, logging.StreamHandler):
                handler.flush()
                handler.close()
            self._logger.removeHandler(handler)


class Config(object):

    """Base Config."""

    LIMIT = 100
    TIMEOUT = None
    USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
    MAXSIZE = 0


class ProdConfig(Config):

    """Prod Config."""

    TIMEOUT = 8
    USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'
    MAXSIZE = 500


class Checker(object):

    """Sitemap Checker."""

    def __init__(self):
        self._logger = Logger()
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._queue = asyncio.Queue(
            maxsize=ProdConfig.MAXSIZE, loop=self._loop)

    def check(self, url):
        """Main() entry-point."""
        start = timer()
        self._loop.run_until_complete(self._fetch_links(url))
        elapsed = time.strftime(
            '%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(timer() - start))
        self._logger._logger.info('time elapsed {}'.format(elapsed))

    async def _fetch_doc(self, client, url):
        """Fetch a sitemap.xml document."""
        self._logger._logger.info('fetching sitemap @ {}'.format(url))
        try:
            async with client.get(
                url=url,
                allow_redirects=True,
                timeout=ProdConfig.TIMEOUT, 
                verify_ssl=True
                    if url.startswith('https') else False) as response:
                response.raise_for_status()
                return await response.text()
        except aiohttp.ClientResponseError as error:
            self._logger._logger.error(
                'sitemap yielded <{}>'.format(
                    error.status))
        except aiohttp.ClientError as error:
            self._logger._logger.error(str(error))
        abort(1)

    async def _producer(self, doc):
        """Parse sitemap.xml and queue discovered links."""
        try:
            root = defusedxml.ElementTree.fromstring(doc)
        except defusedxml.ElementTree.ParseError:
            self._logger._logger.error('failed to parse *.xml document')
            abort(1)
        self._logger._logger.info(
            '*.xml document contains ({}) links'.format(
                len(root)))
        for link in root:
            if link:
                await self._queue.put(''.join(link[0].text.split()))

    async def _consumer(self, client):
        """Process queued links with HEAD requests."""
        while True:
            url = await self._queue.get()
            async with client.head(
                    url=url,
                    allow_redirects=True,
                    timeout=ProdConfig.TIMEOUT, 
                    verify_ssl=True if url.startswith('https') else False) as http:
                self._logger._logger.info(
                    '<{}> {} - {}'.format(http.status, http.reason, url))
                self._queue.task_done()

    async def _fetch_links(self, url):
        """Fetch sitemap.xml links."""
        headers = {'User-Agent': ProdConfig.USER_AGENT}
        connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(
            limit=ProdConfig.LIMIT, loop=self._loop)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
                connector=connector, loop=self._loop, headers=headers) as client:
            doc = await self._fetch_doc(client, url)
            consumer = asyncio.ensure_future(self._consumer(client))
            await self._producer(doc)
            await self._queue.join()
            consumer.cancel()

    def __del__(self):
        if self._loop:
            if not self._loop.is_running:
                self._loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Checker().check(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get your code to run. It imports custom libraries.

Comment: I'll upload the full source, I wish someone said that sooner :)

Comment: @C.Harley I've consolidated everything into one file. I apologize if the formatting is off.

Comment: @1-hit For future reference, you can also have multiple code snippets, signifying (the relevant parts of) each file.

Comment: This is not an answer, I'm curious - if you moved the headers and connector into the __init__ and then in `async with aiohttp.ClientSession` refer to them as self.xxx - would that give you a speed up or break the code? I'm out at the moment and unable to try it myself at this moment.

Comment: @C.Harley I honestly just plugged headers and connector into the session object directly and that seemed to give a minor boost, but not that much.

Comment: You're missing a `import re` btw. I've run the code and it looks fine. So your main thought is your code is slow, but you need to to keep in mind that you're hitting up a google service 310 times from a single IP.

Comment: @C.Harley Oops, I forgot to remove the ``re.compile()`` to replace with ``str.startswith()``. I used Google Flights as a temporary placeholder to demonstrate the usage. Is there a better approach in terms of sending bulk requests?

Comment: That depends on your needs. If you’re going to make a real-time scraper, you need to introduce a multiple-pipe system to handle the requests (proxy). If not, slow it down and store the data temporarily somewhere, and perform comparisons on the next cycle to ensure the data is still valid. Look into the horizontal and vertical scaling techniques and apply the one valid for your goals.

Comment: @C.Harley can you elaborate more on what you meant by multiple-pipe system?

Comment: Like this: https://github.com/rootVIII/proxy_requests

Answer (score 1):

This question is about elapsed timings.
Please update it to include
[cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)
observations or similar wallclock figures.

Reported throughput suggests that processing each URL
takes ~ 660 msec wallclock time.
It would be helpful to note how many milliseconds
of that is local CPU busy time.
It would be interesting to understand how far away
the 95th percentile response time is from the median.

It is unclear if the google end server,
or the e2e internet pipe, could support higher
request rates, and the question does not include
[ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)
or similar benchmark figures.

---

style nit:

```
class Logger(object):
```

Prefer `class Logger:`.
Yes, we know it's inheriting from `object`.
In python2 this used to make a difference to the
[MRO](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html),
but ever since
[sunsetting](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2)
it's not very relevant.

---

The source code looks good, with no obvious flaws.

Ship it.